# Does the Google File System allow listing directory contents?

Tags: database, database-design, file-io, consistency, gfs

In the GFS paper, Section 4.1 describes how GFS is able to make concurrent mutations within a directory while only requiring a read lock on the directory for each client - there's no actual inode in GFS, so clients are free to create, remove, or mutate `/x/y/somefile` while only requiring a read lock on `/x/` and `/x/y/`.

If there are no inodes, then is it still possible to maintain an explicit tree structure? The only way I can see this working is if the master maintains a flattened, 1-dimensional mapping from directory or file names to their metadata, allowing for fast file creation and manipulation.

Suppose that some client of GFS wanted to scan the names of all files in a directory - for instance, `ls`. Without an iteration over all metadata nodes, how is this possible?

It might be possible for a client to maintain their own version of what they think the directory tree looks like in the GFS, but this will only work if each client keeps to their own directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A master lookup table offers access to a single conceptual *tree* of *nodes*. It does this by listing all *paths of names* to nodes. Some nodes are *directories*. The only *data* is owned by non-directory leaf nodes. Eg these paths:

```
/a/b/foo
/a/b/c/bar
/a/baz/
```

describe this tree:

```
\
 a/--b/--foo
 |  \
 |   c/--bar
 baz/
```

Every path identifies a node. The nodes that are the children of a node are the ones whose paths are one name longer in the lookup table. To list a node's children nodes is to list all the paths in the lookup table that are one name longer than its path. What the paper means by *metatdata* is info like whether and how a node is locked and for a non-directory leaf node where its (unshared) data is.

One doesn't navigate by visiting directory nodes that own data that gives child and parent node names and whether they are directories, as in Unix/Linux. Copying a leaf means copying its data to another leaf's, like Unix/Linux cat, not cp. I presume one can copy a subtree, which would add new paths in the lookup table and copy data for non-directory leaves.

One cannot use technical terms like "file" or "directory" as if they mean the same thing in both systems. What one can do is consider GFS and Unix/Linux to both manage the same kind of tree of paths of names through directory nodes to directory leaves and non-directory data-owning leaves. But after that the other parts of the file system state (metadata and data) and their operators differ. In your mind put "GFS-" and "Unix/Linux-" in front of every technical term other than those refering to trees of named nodes.

EDIT: Examples.

1.

> Suppose that some client of GFS wanted to scan the names of all files
>   in a directory - for instance, ls. Without an iteration over all
>   metadata nodes, how is this possible?

A directory listing would return the paths in the lookup table that extend the given directory's path. GFS will offer file server commands to do such things or that support doing such things, hiding its implementation. It would be enough (but slow) to be able iterate through the lookup table. Eg ls /a/b:

```
/a/b/foo
/a/b/c/bar
```

2.
To copy source node children to be target node children: For each path that extends the source's path, add to the lookup table the path got by replacing that prefix by the target path. Presumably the copy command creating the new nodes copies associated data for non-directories. Eg copy children of /a/ to /a/b/c/ adds:

```
/a/b/c/b/foo
/a/b/c/b/c/bar
/a/b/c/baz/
```

giving:

```
\
 a/--b/--foo
 |   \
 |    c/--bar
 |    |--b/--foo
 |    |  \
 |    |   c/--bar
 |    baz/
 baz/
```

Comment: I never denied that a GFS file/directory is distinct from a Linux/Unix one. I accept that. My question is _given that GFS is different_, how _does_ it execute directives that require a tree structure? In order to say, copy a subtree as you mention, does the master fully traverse the entire leaf table for all paths that match the appropriate prefix?

Comment: I didn't say you denied difference. (?) You said you didn't see how it "maintains an explicit tree structure": in the lookup table. Which is not a "leaf table"; it has a path for every node. That's kind of the end of the answer. The GFS file system commands will (somehow) read & change the lookup table and associated file system state. I didn't see anything about implementation of the lookup table (other than prefix compression): it's an abstraction. Metadata "is associated" with a path; there will be a command to get it. But "traversing" is an implementation concept. Does this help?

Comment: Yes - that does clarify some things (please do put what you said into the answer). I understand that the commands will (somehow) read and change the lookup table, but it seems to me that with the locking procedure mentioned in the paper, this (somehow) implementation detail _must_ be a full table traversal (which would be egregiously slow) - if GFS maintained an actual tree just to keep track of which nodes are where, it would need write locks on manipulated directories, which the paper made a point of claiming it doesn't use.

Comment: For instance, in your last example of copying `/a/b/c/`'s children to `/a/` (note I switched the order to avoid self-copying), how would GFS get the names `/a/b/c/*` from its own metadata to do the snapshot? It seems that it _has_ to traverse b/c of the design.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "self copying"--the source has a shape value and one adds a shape like that at the target.

Comment: OK, regarding "self copying," but that's beside the point - what I'm trying to say is there's no (immediately visible) easy way to scan through a directory, which is strange, since the paper references that ability later.

Comment: Any description is at a certain [level of abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computer_science%29). You are assuming implentations. What traversal? What table? What tree? It acts like it has a tree, equivalently it acts like it has a list of paths. Sorry, I don't know what to say. Get more experience with data structures? (Lots of log 2 dealing with trees.)